# How to create a password in the first connection in MySql

Tags: mysql, openssl, password-encryption

I just install Mysql. In a first step I have to define a password to log into the server (localhost in my case).

Here is the command I use in ssl :

```
mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password password_to_use,
```

and that is the output :

```
Invalid command 'mysqladmin'; type "help" for a list.
```

Maybe, you can help.

Comment: It appears that `mysqladmin` is not in your path. You can confirm this with `which mysqladmin` if nothing comes back, then the next step will vary greatly depending on your operating system and how you installed MySQL.

Comment: Here is the output :

Comment: /usr/bin/mysqladmin